# List category posts - Thumbnails are not displaying

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

we've been using List Category Posts to display different category posts on one page and it was working great until recently when the thumbnail images disappear. The 'thumbnail=yes' option is there. We can't figure out how to get the thumbnail images to appear again. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the page: www.tomorrowsyouth.org/programs/international-internships/tyo-intern-alumni/

We're using Version 0.22.3

Comment: Can you add the whole shortcode you're using? Did the thumbnails stop working with the exact same code on update? Did you change anything on your theme's code? Remember you need to enable thumbnails on your theme.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Here's the shortcode we used: [catlist name=tyo_wherearetheynow numberposts=3 excerpt=yes thumbnail=yes template=tyo-alumni] Thumbnails work fine in the blog area of our homepage, so I believe thumbnails are enabled. I will look to see if other plugins could have possible override the thumbnails.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?
I am having a similar issue in that the lists are not displaying sine the last upgrade.
I haven't changed anything else, it just stopped displaying. Thanks Martin

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you have post thumbnails implemented in the theme: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

Another way to more easily use thumbnails is via [WordPress › Get the Image « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-the-image/)

Comment: Thanks for the responses! 

Here's the shortcode we used: [catlist name=tyo_wherearetheynow numberposts=3 excerpt=yes thumbnail=yes template=tyo-alumni]

Thumbnails work fine in the blog area of our homepage, so I believe thumbnails are enabled. I will look to see if other plugins could have possible override the thumbnails.